# Issue in uninstalling and reinstalling Sitecore 6.6 on Windows 8

Tags: windows, sitecore

I have installed sitecore 6.6 on windows 8, but unfortunately I am not able to reinstall it.

When I tried to uninstall through control panel, its not uninstalling properly.

Now when I try to install Sitecore 6.6 on windows 8, it prompting error "Invalid command line argument".

Thanks
Prakash Patel

Comment: I haven't seen this before.  It sounds like a good one for Sitecore support.  What kind of error message are you getting when trying to uninstall the first instance?

Comment: As a work-around, perhaps try to install using a different site name/hostname, then rename your hosts entry and IIS site after installation.

Comment: You also have the option to manual install, there is a zip file of the web root on SDN

Answer (score 2):

Checking out [this page on CMS compatibility](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Installation/CMS%20compatibility.aspx) from sdn.sitecore.net it looks like Sitecore 6.6 does not support windows 8 though it sounds like you've already got it to work ok? As @Ben Golden mentions you could contact Sitecore support about this, but the fact that it's not supported makes me think you might not get very far.